# Spring Component Scanning Error

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

So i recently upgraded to Spring 4.2.1 RELEASE, and i am seeing this error in my context.xml

```
Error occured processing XML 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ScannedGenericBeanDefinition.getFactoryMethodMetadata()Lorg/springframework/core/type/MethodMetadata;'.
```

But the application starts off correctly and everything works fine. What is this error trying to say? My context xml looks like this, and is loaded from web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

What is this error trying to say?

**This got fixed when i downloaded a fresh STS. I had upgraded STS as well. Strange.**

Comment: Yes likewise - Mysterious. The reported error doesn't seem to prevent anything from working though.